# Error when running MCP library - 'rlang_is_formula'

Tags: r, rlang

I'm trying to run a model with the `mcp` [package](https://lindeloev.github.io/mcp/). Here is what I'm running:

```
model <- list(
    response ~ 1,
    ~ 0 + time, 
    ~ 0 + time)
fit <- mcp(model, data=df)
```

This gives the error: `Error in is.type(x) : object 'rlang_is_formula' not found`

I've tried removing and reinstalling the rlang package, with no luck. I'm using R-4.1.2, and rlang is version 1.0.4. `mcp` package is version 0.3.1.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: What version of `mcp` are you using?

Comment: @MrFlick `v-0.3.1`

Answer (score 0):

Detaching other problematic packages and reloading everything did not work. The issue was resolved after reinstalling the mcp package completely.